# How can I store coloured text in variable?

Tags: c++, string, winapi, colors

I want to store text and its colors in variable that I can then `cout`.
I've tried doing it in string like that, but it doesn't work.
I want to have different colors on different words and store it in one variable.

```
string e = "text\ntext" + SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole,64) + 
           "\ntext" + SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole,32);
cout<<e;
```

```
[Error] invalid operands of types 'const char*' and 'const char [6]' to binary
'operator+'
```

Comment: Explicitely cast the `SetConsoleTextAttribute()`: `std::string(SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole,64))`

Comment: `std::cout` doesn't know how to change colors; it only knows how to write characters. There's nothing you can put into a string that would cause `std::cout` to change colors.

Comment: [Console Virtual Terminal Sequences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences).

Answer (score 0):

For the first, SetConsoleTextAttribute function - "Sets the attributes of characters written to the console screen buffer by the WriteFile or WriteConsole function, or echoed by the ReadFile or ReadConsole function. This function affects text written after the function call." That's mean that it doesn't affect in any way on your variable and it's return 0 if it's have a problem or any other if is it okey. This function affect only on console output (on text which will be written after function call).

[For more info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsoletextattribute)

Example:

```
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),64);
    cout << "text\ntext";
```

Comment: Is there any other way of changing text color in c++?

Comment: C++ has no concept of colors. Only the console does. So unless the console accepts color escape codes via `cout`, you will have to use console-specific APIs instead.